# MVC Ajax call stops working after login sometimes

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an ajax call to refresh online friends, and its works properly when I launch the application. But if I login, it stops working sometimes (most, but not all of the time).

Using asp-net-mvc5:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //change the scroll bar
       jQuery('#chatlist').slimScroll({
          color: '#00f',
          size: '10px',
          width: '50px'
       });
       //set periodic refresh of online friends
       var refreshId3 = setInterval("updateOnlineFriendsArea2()", 4000);
    });

   function updateOnlineFriendsArea2() {
      $.ajax({
           url: "/Home/GetOnlineFriedns/",
           dataType: 'json',
           async: true,
           success: function (data) {
                $("#message").html += "Fetching online friends...";
                $("#friendlist").html("");
                var x;
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    for (x in data) {
                      $("#friendlist").html(
                      $("#friendlist").html() +
                      "<li>" +
                      data[x].Username + "</li>");
                    }
               }
               else {
                    $("#chatarea").html("<p>No Messages</p>");
               }
           },
           error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             alert(errorThrown);
           }
       });

       $("#message").html("Messages loaded.");
    }
```

The login controller method that provokes the error:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Validate the user password
            if (await Secrets.Validate(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                string userId = await Logins.GetUserId(IdentityConfig.LocalLoginProvider, model.UserName);
                await SignIn(userId, model.RememberMe);     
                //test
                LoginHelpers.LogUser(User.Identity.GetUserName());
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return View(model);
    }
```

The online friends method on the controller:

```
    [HandleError]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public JsonResult GetOnlineFriedns()
    {
        UserProfile user = Profiles.GetProfileByUsername(this.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
        var result = new LinkedList<object>();
        if (user != null)
        {
            //Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserLogin teste;
            var onlineFriends = ChatMessages.GetOnlineFriedns(user.ID);
            if (onlineFriends != null)
                foreach (var friend in onlineFriends)
                {
                    result.AddLast(new { Username = friend.Username });
                }
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The error displayed:

> syntax error: Unexpected end of input

I am totally lost and can't figure what could be the problem:

- Tasks on sign in?
- Redirecting and partial?
- Bad ajax configuration?

Comment: Can you post the code of your `GetOnlineFriedns` action.

Comment: edited, sry that i forgot to include it before hand